# Python socket broadcast with similar broadcast address

Tags: python, sockets

Assuming you have 2 routers and each uses an IP address of the form 192.168.0.1/24 which means their respective broadcast are of the form 192.168.0.255 and you are connected to both using either Ethernet and Wi-Fi or two Wi-Fi adapters.
Then my question is,  using python inbuilt socket module how would you broadcast to both adapters either by looping or silmutaneously given when I broadcast it's going through only one interface.

Even better would be to choose to which adapter to broadcast to since all have same broadcast I'd.

Thanks

Comment: Each router must have its own network, i.e., different subnets. One could be in 192.168.0.1/24 and another in 192.168.1.1/24.